# How to manipulate a page while it is loading?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I need to build an add-on/extension which remove some elements once they loaded.

How to manipulate a page white it is loading?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [content-scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in google chrome extensions.

Comment: Do you think it is the way which Adblock addons use to block adds?

Comment: As far as I can tell on Chrome yes, it looks like that's how they achieve it.

Comment: No in Adblock, at least in firefox, the ads are prevented from being downloaded. They are not removed after load.

Comment: Do you mean by preventing a GET request from the browser once the page has loaded?